# Многоадресная передача по UDP: несколько клиентов на одной машине

Tags: linux, сокет, передача-данных

Код сервера:

```
#define EXAMPLE_PORT 6000
#define EXAMPLE_GROUP "239.0.0.1"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int sock;
    ssize_t cnt;
    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    char message[50];
    socklen_t addrlen;

    /* set up socket */
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return(1);
    }
    memset((char *)&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    addr.sin_port = htons(EXAMPLE_PORT);
    addrlen = sizeof(addr);

    /* send */
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(EXAMPLE_GROUP);
    while (1) {
        time_t t = time(0);
        sprintf(message, "time is %-24.24s", ctime(&t));
        printf("sending: %s\n", message);
        cnt = sendto(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0,
                     (struct sockaddr *) &addr, addrlen);
        if (cnt < 0) {
            perror("sendto");
            return (1);
        }
        sleep(5);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Код клиента:

```
#define EXAMPLE_PORT 6000
#define EXAMPLE_GROUP "239.0.0.1"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2)
        return 1;

    const char *ip_addr = argv[1];

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int sock;
    socklen_t addrlen;
    ssize_t cnt;
    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    char message[50];

    /* set up socket */
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return(1);
    }
    memset((char *)&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_addr); // *
    addr.sin_port = htons(EXAMPLE_PORT);
    addrlen = sizeof(addr);

    /* receive */
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        return (1);
    }
    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(EXAMPLE_GROUP);
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
                   &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt mreq");
        return (1);
    }
    while (1) {
        cnt = recvfrom(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0,
                       (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addrlen);
        if (cnt < 0) {
            perror("recvfrom");
            return (1);
        } else if (cnt == 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%s: message = \"%s\"\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), message);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос: могу ли я запустить несколько клиентов на одной машине? Сейчас я не могу этого сделать, потому что запуск второго клиента заканчивается ошибкой `address already in use`.

(*) До того, как я захотел использовать IP-адреса конкретных интерфейсов, чтобы биндить сокет, было так:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

Comment: Я вижу в клиенте bind - значит это не клиент, а ещё один сервер

Comment: bind ещё абсолютно не означает, что это сервер. Это вполне может быть и клиент

Comment: @KoVadim странно, никогда не писал UDP-клиентов с bind'ом (а вот без bind'а писал)

Comment: bind привязывает сокет к локальному адресу/порту. Если это не нужно (99% клиентских задач), то и bind не нужен

Comment: Судя по address already in use, не нужно)

Comment: @andreymal, нужно. У меня есть несколько сетевых интерфейсов с адресами из одной сети (eth0 - 10.0.0.101, eth1 - 10.0.0.102 и т.д.), и я хочу одновременно принимать датаграммы по каждому из них.

Comment: @isnullxbh тогда, если я правильно всё понимаю, нужно выбирать порт клиента случайным образом

Comment: @andreymal, черт, а ведь я совсем забыл про него. Спасибо, сейчас попробую!!!

Comment: (хотя может и неправильно понимаю, с мультикастом не работал, зря я в эту тему влез))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию, ОС не дает возможности использовать один и тот же адрес-порт для разных приложений. Но иногда это сильно-сильно нужно. Например, если это наши приложение упало и мы его перезапускаем, то нам не нужно, что бы писало "адрес используется" - мы и так это знаем (ОС не сразу отпускает сокет, что бы старые пакеты не приходили новому приложению).

Ок, как же "исправить"?

```
unsigned int yes = 1;
setsockopt(sock , SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));
```

Вообще то есть ещё и SO_REUSEPORT, но в статье https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/ утвержается, что SO_REUSEADDR включает SO_REUSEPORT

Comment: спасибо, работает!